# Rebuilding Org Agenda Buffer With Timer

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, idle-timer

I am trying to rebuild my *Org Agenda* buffer with a timer. I am trying to do it like this:

```
(defun renewOrgBuffer ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (when (derived-mode-p 'org-agenda-mode)
    (org-agenda-redo t))))
  )
(run-with-idle-timer 60 1000 #'renewOrgBuffer)
```

I basically swiped this from another answer but they wanted to do somehting when the org file saved. I want to update it with a timer and am running into errors.

When I just run the function in `ielm` I get the error: `*** Eval error ***  ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer.`

I am running Emacs 25.1.50.2 client connected to a daemon with org verion 8.2.10 on Ubuntu 15.10.

The purpose for this for me is that I like to have my org file with my todos and appointments up in one buffer and the *Org Agenda* buffer up next to it. So the the main purpose for me to update the *Org Agenda* buffer is just so that the line that says `now - - - - -` updates. It is a small think but I just want to figure it out.

Any help or pointers is appreciated.

**Edit March 7**

I have found that if you enable the sticky agenda view from the dispatcher (* option) then I can call my previously defined `renewOrgBuffer` function interactively with M-x and instead of getting an error, I get a message in the mini buffer that says "org-agenda-list: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer.", which is great, but I don't want to call it interactively every time.

When I try to run that function from the scratch buffer or on a timer like

```
(run-with-idle-timer 3 1000 #'renewOrgBuffer)
```

I get the error:

```
Rebuilding agenda buffer...done
Error running timer ‘renewOrgBuffer’: (error "‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer.")
```

Although it says "Rebuilding agenda buffer...done" it does not actually rebuild it.

Any help with this added information would be helpful, Thank you.

Comment: There are only a few `recenter` in org-mode -- grep them and comment them out, and re-byte-compile if necessary.  Or, find the offending function that has the word `(recenter` and redefine it or use advice.  You want to be able to operate on buffers that are not visible, and `recenter` is preventing you from further developing your new system.  Later on, you can write-in some exceptions for when a window is visible, then recenter . . .  I took care of that in my own setup a long time ago.

Comment: @lawlist If I am using the orgmode version that came with emacs, where is the source? I can only find the compiled elisp files in `/usr/local/share/emacs/25.1.50/lisp/org`. Are you suggesting editing the source and recompiling it? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to download the source-code of the version that you are using.  Then you can word-search for `recenter`.  You can either edit the source and re-byte-compile, or you can just create new functions with the same names for those that need modification.  For example, if the function named `foo` contains a `recenter` command` and `foo` is located in the library named `org-foo.el`, then your `.emacs` can have something like:  `(require 'org-foo) (defun foo (however many arguments) [the modified guts less the recenter garbage]))` and then restart Emacs or evaluate your `.emacs` file.

Comment: @lawlist I did grep around the source and was commenting out different lines where recentering was being used but I also stumbled across `org-agenda-maybe-redo`, which calls `org-agenda-redo` but does some other things making it usable to me. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using the function `org-agenda-maybe-redo` worked instead of `org-agenda-redo`. 
So my renew function now looks like this:

```
(defun renewOrgBuffer ()
  (interactive)
  (dolist (buffer (buffer-list))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (when (derived-mode-p 'org-agenda-mode)
    (org-agenda-maybe-redo))))
  )
```

and I made a timer to renew the agenda buffers:

```
(run-with-idle-timer 3 1000 #'renewOrgBuffer)
```

comparing `org-agenda-redo` and `org-agenda-maybe-redo`, it appears that maybe my issue was that I wasn't using the `get-buffer-window` function.

Comment: The last line of `org-agenda-redo` is `(recenter window-line)` -- so you could just rewrite that function to comment out the last line -- same procedure mentioned above:  `(require 'org-agenda) (defun org-agenda-redo (&optional all) . . . [everything but the last line of code relating to recentering])`  You simply cannot call `recenter` on a buffer unless it is visible in a window, or else it will throw an error.  You could also write in an exception to recenter only when the buffer window is visible.

Comment: Yes I did see that. What I had done was copied the function into my scratch buffer and then I commented out that line and loaded it in with `C-x C-e`. I still had the issue, making me think that the recenter function was being called somewhere else as well.

Comment: It's possible it came from somewhere else, but there are no more than 10 places in the latest version of `org-mode` that call `recenter`.  It's not likely coming from any location other than `org-mode`.